# Gitlab CI/CD Maven dependency from private package registry: Could not find artifact

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci

community.

I have a Maven package registry hosted in a project that belongs to a group.
In that registry I manually uploaded an artifact (pom and jar files) using a personal access token.

I have a project that uses that artifact from that package registry. So, when I try to execute the **test** stage, it fails with this error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:get (default-cli) on project docker_receiver: Couldn't download artifact: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact transparent_coach:maven_registry:jar:1.0.0 in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/23241686/packages/maven)`

This is the **test** stage I am running:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: false
  tags:
    - docker
    - dind
  script:
    - mvn --version
    - echo "$TC_GITLAB_AUTH_SETTINGS" > settings.xml
    - mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=transparent_coach:maven_registry:1.0.0
    - mvn clean verify
```

The `settings.xml` file is present and it contains the correct structure with the same personal token I used for uploading the artifact to the registry. Parameters for the registry and the artifact in `pom.xml` are correct:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>transparent_coach</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven_registry</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

#----------------------

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/23241686/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/23241686/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>

  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/23241686/packages/maven</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

A [similar thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/dependency-in-private-package-registry-could-not-find-artifact/47848) mentioned:

> In the end I found out that the authentication needed to be done first. It is simply the wrong error message.
>
> Make sure you have `ci_settings.xml` in your project that you use for your `mvn` commands with `-s ci_settings.xml`.

Try also increasing the Maven log level to get more detailed information on what is going wrong by using the `-X` option in the Maven commands, which will enable debug output, as follows:

```yaml
- mvn --settings ci_settings.xml -X dependency:get -Dartifact=transparent_coach:maven_registry:1.0.0
```

The `--settings ci_settings.xml` is there to make sure you [are using the `ci_settings.xml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#create-maven-packages-with-gitlab-cicd) you think you are, and not one set by default. You can add a step to cat (display) its content, in order to confirm the URL is correctly specified in it.
And make sure the project ID in the URL (`23241686`) is correct.

As mentioned above, the authentication should be set in that `ci_settings.xml` (I took inspiration from [this `ci_settings.xml`](https://gitlab.waveinformatica.com/ocean/ocean/-/blob/a0e143427dda036f1cc2574c6e7550af0749c1bf/ci_settings.xml)):

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpConfiguration>
          <all>
            <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
          </all>
        </httpConfiguration>
      </configuration>
      <username>oauth2</username>
      <password>${env.CI_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```